# How do you get a list of tables name that contains a specific column name on Firebird?

Tags: firebird

I have to find a table (or more than one) that contains a column named 'idRec' on a Firebird database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query the [`RDB$RELATION_FIELDS`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref-appx04-relfields.html) table for this:

```sql
select RDB$RELATION_NAME
from RDB$RELATION_FIELDS
where RDB$FIELD_NAME = 'idRec'
```

This will only match columns that are actually called `idRec` (and thus are required to be quoted when used in SQL statements). If you are actually looking for a column called `IDREC` (unquoted object names are stored in uppercase), use `where RDB$FIELD_NAME = 'IDREC'`